# How to access a specific data on array for assembly 8086

Tags: arrays, assembly, masm, x86-16

Let's say I have the index I want to access store on a variable called index.

I have trying to access that specific data of array using code like this

```
mov si, OFFSET array
mov al,[si+index]
mov ah,09h
mov bl,0eh   
mov cx,1          
int 10h
```

The code is not allowing me to access that specific data of the array

Comment: "not allowing me to access" - What does that mean?  Are you getting an error at assembly time?  Run time?  Is it just not printing the value you expect?

Comment: ok let,s say i have the index to be 2, and if I execute the code above, It doesn't print the 3rd data from the array, rather it prints some other number

Comment: @DavidWohlferd I think I have figured it out. I just created a loop to increment the si to index.

Comment: You're using the address of `array` as an offset from `index`.  i.e. the address you were loading from is `OFFSET array + OFFSET index`.  I think you want `mov si, index` / `mov al, [array + si]`.  You always need an array index to be in a register, unless it's an assemble-time constant.

Comment: this code is incomplete and it is missing the vital part, what is `index`. If you did something like `index equ 2` having it as constant, your code would work. If you have something like `index db 2`, then you may want to adjust your thinking for assembly, it's not variable. The `db 2` part emits one byte of machine code (with value 2) into the binary. The part `index` doesn't emit any machine code, but defines symbolic label to the memory address of the "current" position in machine code, i.e. where that byte `2` will land. And in `mov al,[si + index]` index is used as address (not value).

Comment: I.e. your result is `al <- [offset array + offset index]` which is some value from memory where you didn't expect read. To use the index "variable" you would have to read it first, i.e. `movzx si,byte ptr [index]` `mov bx,offset array` `mov al,[bx + si]` ... but generally it is more efficient to keep "hot" values/variables in registers only, as memory access is much slower, so it makes more sense to do only `mov si,offset array` ahead of loop, and then just `inc si` to advance the pointer by +1, if the array contain bytes. (for words you need `add si,2`, for 32 bit elements `add si,4`, etc...)